# I need simple debugger source

Tags: windows, development, debug

How can I write a simple debugger for Windows? I need to launch another program (do not attach to an already running one, but launch it yourself) then to let it run and to catch it at a certain address. Moreover, the breakpoint must be set via hardware debugging registers, not by just 0xCC. I did not find any source code for an example of such thing over the Internet, alas.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an RE question but MSDN has an [example of the main loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/writing-the-debugger-s-main-loop).
I also found this tutorial:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger

Comment: I need to write a launcher for some program so that the program unpacks itself and then stops at its unpacked code. The fact is that I can't use 0xCC, it will be overwritten during the unpacking so I need to make a stop using HDR to stop on execution at a certain address.

I saw the link to MSDN you mentioned, but it shows just a skeleton, no specifics. Thanks for the second link, it's more clear there. The question remains: how to use HDR? Am I have to modify their values via say SetThreadContext? I did not find any WinAPI for manipulating exactly the values ​​of hardware debug registers.

Comment: And yes, the program I try to dig in is packed (protected) with Themida, so it's quite an RE question :-) I need Themida unpack its stuff first and then I get down to the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading Grey Hat Python where they take you through writing your own debugger, maybe that would be a good start.